# Eliminar un fichero con todo su contenido en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Quisiera eliminar un directorio que contiene varios ficheros dentro. Tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
carpeta
    fichero1.txt
    fichero2.txt
```

he intentado eliminarlo directamente con `os.removedirs('carpeta')`pero me da el error `Directory not empty: 'carpeta'`. También intente eliminar primero los ficheros y después el directorio de la siguiente forma:

```
import os
os.remove('carpeta/fichero1.txt')
os.remove('carpeta/fichero2.txt')
os.removedirs('carpeta')
```

Esto, aunque me borra los ficheros, cuando va a eliminar la carpeta me sigue dando el mismo error; y aunque funcionara no me es recomendable porque no se cuantos ficheros voy a tener en esa carpeta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para eliminar el directorio y todo su contenido usa [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) de la biblioteca estándar. Hay otras opciones como usar comandos propios del sistema operativo usando `os.system` o `subprocess`,  pero esto es lo más simple.

```
import shutil
shutil.rmtree("carpeta")
```

Además, es plataforma-independiente.